# MSChart CandleStick Color Options Powershell

Tags: winforms, powershell, mschart, candlestick-chart

I am writing a process in Powershell to give me a 30 day rolling Candlestick chart.  I have everything working.  But the one thing that is bugging me is that the wick line(min,max) is blue (the default MSChart color).  I can't find any option to change this.

Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: Do you have [Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422) installed?

Comment: Why is this the first question.  Shouldn't that be implied in my opening where I stated I have everything working and that the only thing bugging me was the blue wick line.  How would anything be working if I didn't have that installed?

Comment: Powershell and .Net are extremely flexible. Without knowing anything about what has been done to get "everything working" it is difficult to know whether you are working with Windows XP and Powershell 1.0 with .Net 2.0 or if you're on Windows 8.1 with Powershell 4.0 and .Net 4.5. Answers for this sort of thing are going to vary quite a bit depending on what is installed and what methods are being used.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using **Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5** You can set any data point color like this...

```
$Chart.Series["Data"].Points[$index].Color = [System.Drawing.Color]::Red
```

Where $index is the index of your data point.

If you want to color Max and Min, you have to find them and set the color.

```
$maxPoint = $Chart.Series["Data"].Points.FindMaxByValue()
$maxPoint.Color = [System.Drawing.Color]::Red

$minPoint = $Chart.Series["Data"].Points.FindMinByValue()
$minPoint.Color = [System.Drawing.Color]::Green
```

Read [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/richard_macdonald/archive/2009/04/28/3231887.aspx) for more detailed explanation.

Comment: I should have responded yesterday afternoon.  I found a way to do it, but the option just didn't stick out quite like some of the other.  I don't want to use the above code because I want the entire series to be the same without repetition.  Here is how you can change it.

 $CHART.Series["SERIESNAME"].color = "Some color"

Comment: @This_is_Mine, no problem. I'm glad you have found a solution. Please do document it as an answer and accept the answer. It helps this site help others with the same issue in the future.